# running postgres in nodejs on browser

Tags: node.js, postgresql, browser

I developing a nodejs application that is supposed to be broweser based since I want to make it a chrome extension later on. I am using Postgres (pg-promise) for the database but it is not running correctly on the browser because these libraries only work on server side. Any ideas how I can get over the issue?

Comment: You need to setup the server to make that request. Client js sends request to server (via AJAX or Socket or whatever) and server makes the database request and returns to the user. A little more explanation of what you've tried already and how your architecture is setup would be helpful.

Comment: `pg-promise` is for server-side only. You need to create an HTTP service with `pg-promise` which then can be used from the browser.

Comment: I have an HTTP service that is running the pg-promise but I am getting stuck on how to connect it with the client side code which is a different project